# What Emacs Lisp function is to `require` as `autoload` is to `load`?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to program GNU Emacs 23 to issue `require` commands lazily, on demand, instead of up front in my `.emacs` file.   If I wanted to delay the execution of  a `load` command, I could use `autoload`.  But `require` and `load` take different sorts of arguments.

Is there a predefined function that does for `require` the same job that `autoload` does for `load`?  And if not, what tools would people recommend that I use to roll my own?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd use this that you couldn't do with `autoload`?

Comment: (might help) http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_library_system.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not difference between `require` and `load` with regards to `autoload`.  `require` is just a frontend to `load`, which more or less comes down to:

```
(defun require (feature &optional filename noerror)
  (unless (featurep feature)
    (let ((filename (or filename (symbol-name feature))))
      (load filename noerror))))
```

As you can see, the symbol name given to `require` is equal to the filename given to `load`.  As a matter of fact, the first `(require 'foo)` evaluated in an Emacs session is equivalent to `(load "foo")`.

Thus, you can just use `(auto-load 'foo-function "foo")` for `foo-function` from the library `foo`, that you can load with `(require 'foo)`.

Answer (score 4):

One more answer to help clarify (this was a little verbose for a comment):

- `autoload` says "if this *function* isn't already defined, then `load` this file (if and when the function is called)."
- `require` says "if this *library* isn't already loaded, then `load` this file (immediately)."

Note in particular that you don't *need* to use `require` to load a library; that's simply the way you ensure that you don't load it *again* (assuming you don't want to do that). The `(provide 'FEATURE)` expression in the library will be evaluated no matter how the library was loaded, which lets any future `require` know that it doesn't need to do anything.

It's a similar situation for `autoload` -- if the file has already been loaded (and therefore the function in question properly defined), then the autoload no longer has any effect.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of "demand" do you have in mind for your "on demand"?

1. If a given command or other function needs (or soft-needs) a given library, then *that function* itself can use `(require 'foo)` or `(require 'foo nil t)`. The library will be loaded on demand from that function.
2. Consider also whether you might need to load the file more than once, i.e., reload it in some situations, whether or not it has already been loaded.

For #2, for instance, my code that uses a library of Lisp macros, [`icicles-mac.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/icicles-mac.el) does not just use `require`, because I want to make sure that if a user gets a *new version* of that library (e.g., downloads a new source version and byte-compiles it) then that new version is used whenever s?he byte-compiles another library that needs it.  (This is important -- when a library of macros changes, other libraries that use those macros generally need to be recompiled after loading the new macros file.)  For that, instead of just `(require 'icicles-mac)` I use this:

```
 (eval-when-compile
  (or (condition-case nil
          (load-library "icicles-mac") ; Use load-library to ensure latest .elc.
        (error nil))
      (require 'icicles-mac)))         ; Require, so can load separately if not on `load-path'.
```